# Including a .js file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to include this script in my app: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I have saved it in a file called lib/latlon.js, and I am trying to include it like this:

```
require('./lib/latlon.js');
```

How should I go about including a JS library like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you should take a look at the Modules documentation for node.js:
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.5/api/modules.html

The script you're trying to include is not a node.js module, so you should make a few changes to it. As there is no shared global scope between the modules in node.js you need to add all the methods you want to access to the exports object. If you add this line to your latlon.js file:

```
exports.LatLon = LatLon;
```

...you should be able to access the LatLon function like this:

```
var LatLonModule = require('./lib/latlon.js');
var latlongObj = new LatLonModule.LatLon(lat, lon, rad);
```

Comment: Almost: if you set `exports.LatLon`, you get at it with `require('./lib/latlon.js').LatLon`. To use `require` like in your example, `latlon.js` needs to export itself with `module.exports = LatLon`.

Comment: Sure. But, it's perfectly OK to do `module.exports = LatLon`, or to skip saving the module to a variable and set `varLatLon = require('./lib/latlon.js').LatLon` in one step — they're both common patterns.

Comment: I have only used module.exports to return an instance. The LatLon constructor takes parameters. How would that work?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't care, functions are objects just like everything else! In the module: `module.exports = LatLon;`. In the application: `var LatLon = require('latlon');`. Later: `var someLatLon = new LatLon(param, param, param);`.

Comment: I have similar requirement, trying to use a library and i have set as given above. I get module not found error. NOTE : i haven't done any changes to the library file. HERE is what i set var epson = require('./epos-print-3.0.0.js').epson;

Comment: Try to figure out where to module file is located. Did you install it globally or in the project. Is it in the node_modules folder?

Comment: No its not in node_modules...its in my project. In some .js file i am trying to include that....

Comment: The whole idea is, creating an object of that 3rd party library and use it in my .js file.

Comment: Do you require the file with a path relative to the file it is required from? It should be `./mymodule.js` if it is in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, i did the same as you can see in my previous comment. Is there any other settings required ??. I haven't touched that library file. Will node be able to read the functions if i create object ??

Comment: I know it is possible to set which paths node should look for modules in, but if you haven't changed anything, your code should be correct.

Comment: It doesn't have anything like "module.exports" in that library file. I am unsure on its usage. As it was a library file i didn't touch it

Comment: @Jørgen i have added a question for your reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714632/module-exports-inclusion-library-file